# Set up Google Analytics Goal for Magento newsletter

Tags: magento, google-analytics, newsletter, subscriber, goal-tracking

I'm looking to set up a Google Analytics Goal for newsletter subscriptions on a Magento (1.7) website. The form is pointing to 'newsletter/subscriber/new/'. A) will this url work as a Goal URL in Google Analytics? B) where can I find this folder in the Magento structure?

I'm wondering whether I can check whether GA code has been added to whatever page in this newsletter/subscriber/new/ folder it's pointing to so it will be tracked?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look @ [_trackPageview(opt_pageURL)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview)

Then in your newsletter template you could do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');

    newsletterSubscriberFormDetail.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {

            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/newsletter/subscriber/successful']);

            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }.bind(newsletterSubscriberFormDetail);
//]]>
</script>
```

Then create you goal url as '/newsletter/subscriber/successful';

You could also just add this line to the button onclick/submit event but it wouldn't be accurate because it before the data is validated

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/newsletter/subscriber/successful']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for B is, that there is no specific folder for this: 
the URL `newsletter/subscriber/new/` references to the method `newAction()`, which you can find by examining the URL: the first element `newsletter` refers to the newsletter modul (`Mage/Newsletter`), the second element `subscriber` refers to the controller in this modul `Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php`), third element refers to the action `newAction()` in this controller.
Inside the `newAction()` method is a redirect defined: `$this->_redirectReferer();`
This method `_redirectReferer()` is inherited from the class `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`:

```
protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
{

    $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
    if (empty($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    return $this;
}
```

So, by subscribing to the newsletter, the method `newAction()` gets called, which in the end redirects to the page given in the referer, it is the same page you started the subscription. Given a basic Magento Installation, the frontend template for the newsletter subscription block is `app/design/frontend/base/default/newsletter/subscription.phtml`.

I don't know how Google Analytic Goals are set up, but this might help you as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for that, that means that newsletter/subscriber/new/ won't work. The subscription block is frontend/em0021/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml. I just wonder if adding this path is enough to show whether subscription is successful,as when you enter your email address in the subscription box you don't move away from the actual page, only a message appears at the top of the page saying 'Thank you for your subscription.' For GA goals you specify a 'Thank you' page as destination to prove it's been successful. Maybe I'll try and add this .phtml page in GA goals and see what happens.

Comment: If you need a redirect to a special page, you can find an easy solution here, just adding some code to your subscription form: http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/magento-redirect-page-newsletter-subscription/ . For general use of Magentos redirect methods this might help: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-redirect-functions/ , but for this i think you would have to override the `SubscriberController.php` in a custom modul, so first solution is easier..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. At the moment not looking to redirect but may do it this last thing doesn't work: I've set up a second goal with an Event (rather than URL destination) with as Action: /newsletter/subscriber/new/. I'll have to see if one of them will return some result and will post it here if they work.